# SBT using dependencyTree and evicted

Tags: sbt

I ran sbt dependencyTree on sbt 1.5.5 and it prints the dependency tree and this

```
[error] (evicted) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error] 
[error]         * org.typelevel:cats-core_2.12:2.6.1 (semver-spec) is selected over {2.6.0, 2.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.0, 2.4.2, 2.3.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.2, 2.4.2, 2.1.0, 1.1.0}
[error]             +- org.typelevel:cats-effect_2.12:2.5.0               (depends on 2.6.1)
[error]             +- org.typelevel:cats-free_2.12:1.1.0                 (depends on 1.1.0)
[error]             +- io.circe:circe-core_2.12:0.13.0                    (depends on 2.1.0)
```

So what I understand from this is that there are multiple versions of cats-core, coming from cats-effect, cats-free and circe.
But i can't find org.typelevel:cats-free nor circe-core in the dependecyTree which is printed. Shouldn't it be there ?

How do i know where are these dependencies coming from?

I want to track them so i can bump their version.

edit:
i also tried  `whatDependsOn org.typelevel cats-free_2.12`
but i just get the same evicted error

full tree: https://gist.github.com/adrian-salajan/97e0e5ae3fe5fb35b81a651c295f8a6e

Comment: Yes these dependencies should appear in the dependency tree. Can you maybe share the list of dependencies you use and the full output of `dependency tree`? Hoping the list is not too long..

Comment: Added a gist containing almost the full tree (company packages removed)

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6618